# Sync audio with scrolling text for website

Tags: audio, text, web, synchronization

I have about 5 paragraphs of text that will vertically scroll in a window and I need to be able to sync audio with it. It doesn't necessarily need to have the words highlighted as it's being read, but just accurate start and ending times.  I tried to make something in Flash with ActionScript but I'm not very good with it and can't get satisfactory results.

I've googled and youtubed like crazy for tutorials or assistance but just can't really seem to find anything. If someone can help or point me in the right direction, it would be very much appreciated.